# Good practice using NodeJS + ES6 import

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm starting a simple backend server using NodeJS and Typescript, to take advantage of its autocomplete/type detection features.

In previous applications, all the database logic was inside a `db.js` file, which is imported where needed using `require`. So far, it's been working good, but I'd like to give a try to importing modules using `import`, just to see its pros and cons, and I'd like some advice.

My plan is to create a class to handle all the database logic and keep the connection information. Something like:

**db.ts**

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

export class AppDB {
  // Will store the connection, note that it's STATIC
  static sequelize: Sequelize;

  constructor() {
    // Connect to the DB and store the connection in the class property
    AppDB.sequelize = this.connect(.....);
  }
}
```

This way, I could access the database connection from all the routes or models using:

**models/example_model.ts**

```
import { AppDB } from 'db/db';

....
  AppDB.sequelize.query(...);
....
```

My question is: Is this a good way of sharing an object through the application? Does it have any disadvantages over using `require`?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: [ES Modules in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) are still experimental. So no, it is not good practice (yet?).

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript, `import` can only be used if there is a types declaration file (`*.d.ts`).
The `require` keyword ignores those types and completely removes the use of types for that particular library.

This is a fine way of achieveing your goal to use the same database connection in different files.